# RabbitMQ not running on mac

Tags: rabbitmq, homebrew

I have installed RabbitMQ on my mac using homebrew when I run this command

```
rabbitmq-server
```

I get the following error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtinfo.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hennie/anaconda3/lib/erlang/erts-7.3/bin/beam.smp
  Reason: image not found
/Users/hennie/anaconda3/lib/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 89: 22706 Abort trap: 6           NOTIFY_SOCKET= RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=$RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE RABBITMQ_DIST_PORT=$RABBITMQ_DIST_PORT ${ERL_DIR}erl -pa "$RABBITMQ_EBIN_ROOT" -boot "${CLEAN_BOOT_FILE}" -noinput -hidden -s rabbit_prelaunch ${RABBITMQ_NAME_TYPE} ${RABBITMQ_PRELAUNCH_NODENAME} -extra "${RABBITMQ_NODENAME}"
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open an issue in [the homebrew repository](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues).